# Loopback - Add existent object to has many property via id

Tags: node.js, has-many, loopbackjs

I want to relate two instance objects `A` and `B`. In my A model definition, `A hasMany B`.

Now loopback default endpoints let me create a new B object related to A, but what happens when I do not want to create a new object, I just want to relate two existent objects.

I would like to post the relation, not the object. Is this posible?

Comment: Can you solve this problem? I have same question.